# PlotStyle with Table

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I want to create a plot style with a table and manipulate the variables in the plot style.

```
Menge = {g, h};
Manipulate[
  Plot[{0.5 x + 1, x}, {x, -1, 5},
    PlotStyle -> Table[Opacity[Menge[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[Menge]}]],
{g, {1, 0}}, 
{h, {1, 0}}]
```

This code won't work. But when i create the table and simply copy the output it works.
Can someone help me out?

Comment: ah sorry. i mixed up the variables.
That's just a small example. I justs want the PlotStyle to be generated from a set like Menge. The arguments for the Manipulate should also be generated from Menge. This i have already working, but i'm struggling with the plotstyle.

Comment: `g` inside `Manipulate` is not the same as the one in `Menge`. `Manipulate` is scoping `h` ang `g`. Try adding `Initialization :> (Menge = {g, h};) to the manipulate.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

Edit: `Menge` outside as OP wants.

```
Menge := {g, h};
Manipulate[
 Dynamic@Plot[{0.5 x + 1, x}, {x, -1, 5}, PlotStyle -> Opacity /@ Menge],
 {g, {1, 0}}, {h, {1, 0}}, 
 LocalizeVariables -> False]
```

Comment: nearly. I want the Elements of Menge to come from "outside" of the manipulate. In my sheet Menge is a quite big set which is generated dynamically. The arguments for the Manipulate i generate with $Evaluate@(Sequence @@ 
   Table[{Menge[[i]], {1, 0}}, {i, 1, Length[Menge]}])$ and now i also want to generate the PlotStyle dynamically to show and hide my plotted functions which i generated earlier.

Comment: @user11004 Ok, so you can use `LocalizeVariables->False` or,what I strongly recommend, use `DynamicModule` to have full control what is important for bigger projects.

Comment: Thank you! LocalizeVariables solved my problem. But i will have a look at DynamicModule! Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 3):

I  really don't see the value of having a list of opacity control variables external to the `Manipulate` expression. Were you to change the external list, you would still have to edit the `Manipulate` to add or remove slider controls to support your changes. So why not just do it all in the `Manipulate` expression?

```
Manipulate[
  Dynamic @ Plot[{0.5 x + 1, x}, {x, -1, 5}, PlotStyle -> Opacity /@ vars],
  {{op1, 1, "g-opacity"}, 0, 1, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{op2, 1, "h-opacity"}, 0, 1, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {vars, ControlType -> None},
  Initialization :> (vars := {op1, op2})]
```

[image: plot.png]

Answer (score 1):

If you want `Menge` to be global then the minimum alteration to what you have done to get this to work would be this:

```
Manipulate[
 Dynamic@Plot[{0.5 x + 1, x}, {x, -1, 5},
   PlotStyle -> Opacity /@ Menge[g, h]],
 {{g, 1}, 0, 1},
 {{h, 1}, 0, 1},
 Initialization :> {Menge[g_, h_] := {g, h}}]
```

[image]

I always would recommend that you have your external function(s) within `Initialization`. From there you can add other things to make it look pretty.